# Override login form submisssion

Tags: hooks, users

I try to call a SOAP web service before an users authentication. I've try this

```
function beneficiaire_user_login(&$edit, $account){
    die('hello from login override'); }
```

Unfortunately, if my SOAP request is bad I cannot prevent the authentication.

What I want to do is:
click the login > check via a WS is the user exists > if yes create the user on Drupal, else show an error message.
Can I perform this action before the session opening ?

With a form_alter hook, it doesn't works, I do not see the "form alter" text

```
function beneficiaire_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id){
    exit('form alter');
}
```

Thanks

Comment: YOU HAVE TO VALIDATE THE LOGIN FORM AS CUSTOM VALIDATION

Comment: Clear the cache

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on something similar. I think you can do this using a validation rule.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 * We replace the local login validation handler with our own.
 */
 function beneficiaire_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    // In this simple example we authenticate on username to see whether starts with dave
    if ($form_id == 'user_login' || $form_id == 'user_login_block') {
        $form['#validate'][] = 'beneficiaire_user_form_validate';
    }
 }

/**
 * Perform validation rules and set error states
 */
function beneficiaire_user_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
    if (!beneficiaire_authenticate($form_state)) {
        form_set_error('name', t('You are not on our super-secret list.'));
    }
}

/**
 * Custom user authentication function
 */
 function beneficiaire_authenticate(&$form_state) {
     // Check the webservice here and return false if user not found.
 }
```

Comment: Oops! Didn't realize I was responding to an old question.